# How can I find out the number of days in between two dates in python

Tags: date, days

I have a problem where I need to find the number of days between any two given dates from a list of dates is there anywhere to find out the number of days between the given dates.

the given dates are:
06/06/2012
08/08/2012
10/10/2012
12/12/2012
and the last day of feburary

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is `deltatime`; in particular, it is what type you get when you subtract 2 date(time)s.

Comment: how would I write it then if I wanted to find the number of days between 06/06/2012 and 08/08/2012 and express the answers in days